# Stop a thread from outside

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a thread doing things in background and I want to suspend it whenever my program has a real thing to do. Once that is finished I want the background thread to continue. E.g.

```
ta = Thread.new { loop { print 'a'; sleep 0.2 } }

sleep 0.5

# put ta to sleep
5.times { print 'b'; sleep 0.2 }
# let ta resume

sleep 0.8
puts
```

The output should be something like `aaabbbbbaaaaa`. Currently it is `aaabababababaaaaa`.

Although a thread can stop itself through `Thread.stop`, I found no method to stop a thread from "outside". Is there a simple solution?

Comment: I did some research and I haven't found anything in the `Thread` class (which you did yourself, I assume). From `#ruby`: JonnieCache: you need a system of locks/semaphores/etc. prepare for pain.
https://github.com/igrigorik/agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `Mutex`:

```
$my_mutex = Mutex.new

t1 = Thread.new do
  loop do
    $my_mutex.synchronize do
      print 'a'
    end
    sleep 0.2
  end
end

sleep 0.5

$my_mutex.synchronize do
  5.times do
    print 'b'
    sleep 0.2
  end
end

sleep 0.8

puts
sleep
```

Output:

```
aaabbbbbaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work. But a restriction is that the thread to be stopped has to be cooperative and release/reclaim the mutex regularily. I was hoping for something to enforce stopping.